# Prolog: Append elements in a list to a list

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, append

I'm trying to create a program that given: combine([[1],[2,3]],Q). it will generate: Q=[1,2,3].

In other words, if I'm given a list of elements I need to append all of them into a single list. Not every element may be a list, so I must have any non-list elements become lists so it is possible to append. Whatever other elements that are contained in the list elements do not matter.

My attempt so far:

```
combine(L,Q) :- match(L,Q).

match([],Q).
match([H|T],Q) :- H = [], append(H,Q,Z), match(T,Z).
match([H|T],Q) :- H = [_|_], append(H,Q,Z), match(T,Z).
match([H|T],Q) :- append([H],Q,Z), match(T,Z).
```

My idea behind this is that when I call the helper function, I attempt to find out if H is a list or non-list. If it is a non-list it will put H in a list and append it to list being passed recursively. The top fact cancels when the list reaches the end. Sadly, what I'm getting is Q = [*giberish*,*giberish*,...]; Q = [*more gibberish*,....];

EDIT: Fixed description of what I need.

Comment: What would you expect `Q` to be from `combine([[1],[2,[3]]],Q)`?

Comment: I would expect: Q=[1,2,[3]].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go.  Basically, if the list is empty, so is the flattened version.  If it isn't append the first element to the flattened version of the rest, but if the head isn't a list, make it one first.

```
combine([],[]).
combine([H|T],Q) :- is_list(H), combine(T,Q1), append(H,Q1,Q).
combine([H|T],Q) :- not(is_list(H)), combine(T,Q1), append([H],Q1,Q).
```

Comment: Makes sense. Appreciate it!